# Difference between data and host volume in Docker containers?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-volume

As far as I know, there are 2 options for using volume in Docker:

**1.** Mount a host directory as data volume:

```
docker run -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" -e "MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=<YourStrong!Passw0rd>" -p 1433:1433 
-v <host directory>/data:/var/opt/mssql/data 
-d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
```

**2.** Use data volume containers:

```
docker run -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" -e "MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=<YourStrong!Passw0rd>" -p 1433:1433 
-v sqlvolume:/var/opt/mssql -d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
```

My questions:

**1)** In the 1st option, I think data in the `/var/opt/mssql/data` is completely kept on `<host directory>`. But in the 2nd option, where is it kept in the Docker data files?

**2)** Let's say I have a currently used container where `/var/opt/mssql/data` is stored and then decide to mount it to a `<host directory>`. In this scene, can I move this data directly to the host directory using the `docker run` command in the 2nd option? Or should I backup and restore this data?

**3)** When mounting data in a host directory and deleting all the containers and uninstalling Docker, we still have the data. So, after reinstalling the Docker and mounting the same database to the same host, will we get the same data before uninstalling Docker?

Comment: I had some time this morning and I usually like to be a helpful guy, so I decided to answer your question. Meanwhile it definitely shows you did not spend a lot of time reading the documentation nor experimenting on your side (which is probably why someone decided it deserved a down vote). Rather than asking "why you dowvoted?" (without any proof) or begging for up-votes, take this as a sign your question needs to be improved. And if you really don't like the risk being downvoted, just don't use SO, because it will happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Your bind mounted data is kept in the bind-mounted folder on your host. Nothing really mysterious about that. For docker volumes, in most typical situations, the data is kept on your docker host. The exact place and folder architecture depends on your configuration, more specifically on the [storage driver in use](https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/select-storage-driver/). Meanwhile, inspecting `/var/lib/docker/volumes` is probably a good start to look under the hood. Note that some drivers support storing data over the network (e.g. `vieux/sshfs`...), but from your question I doubt you use any of those at the moment.
2. I'm not totally sure what you are asking here. Meanwhile, one feature available with docker volumes (and not with bind mounts, i.e. mounting a host folder to the container) is the ability to [copy the content from the path in the image to a freshly created volume](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#populate-a-volume-using-a-container) when the container starts.
3. Data is data, wherever you keep it. If you have any sort of (thoroughly tested!) backup, you will always be able to restore it and feed it to your new container. The situation is usually quite easy to visualize regarding bind-mounts for docker beginners (i.e. backup the folder on the host, restore it and bind-mount it back to a new container). If you decide to work with volumes (which is probably a good suggestion as explained in the [volume documentation introduction](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#populate-a-volume-using-a-container)), see [Backup, restore, or migrate data volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#backup-restore-or-migrate-data-volumes) to get a first idea of how to proceed.

Comment: Many thanks for your detailed explanations, voted up ;) On the other hand, I need some details about the points above.

Comment: **#1** I use Windows and before latest versions of Docker, I think the data was kept on Program Data folder. But after WLS2 support, it may be kept in the Linux part installed for WLS2 support. IS that true?

Comment: **#2** Your example is useful. I just want to learn that, lets say I have a data in my database in a Docker container (not mounted to a volume). Then I decide to move the database to a volume in my host directory. In this scene, I think I can easily transfer this data my mounting and restarting the Docker? Is that true? If so, what about the old data? Will it be still kept in the container?

Comment: **#3** Actually I would prefer to backup database instead of Docker container or volume for now. So, I just asked to continue with the previous data files without get backup. The scenario is like that: I have a database and its data is mounted to host directory. Then I delete Docker containers and uninstall Docker. Then install Docker and mount the new database's data folder to the previous data directory in my host. Then I think I can get the previous data without any backup/restore operation? Is that true?

Comment: #1 - I have no idea I don't know windows. #2 - you can copy files from a folder to an other, mounted or not, help yourself. Just try it, it will be faster than asking question. #3 - yes.